# Is it possible to target an input element using @keyup inside a custom component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I wanted to target an input element inside a custom component using v-on:keyup, but apparently I have no luck

```
 <TextField label="Some Text" @keyup="updateLen" v-model="text"  />

//javascript
computed: {
updatedLen(event) {
  let target = event.value.length;

  console.log('target', target)
},
}
```

here is the custom component src code

```
<template>
<div>
<v-text-field>@keyup="keyUp"</v-text-field>
</div>
</template>

<script>
keyUp(event)
    {
      
      this.content =   this.content.replace(/([^a-z0-9-]+)/gi, '');
        

      this.$emit('input', this.content);
     
    },
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On custom components, listeners like `@myEvent` will listen to custom events emitted with `this.$emit`. So here, `@keyup` is listening to custom events `this.$emit('keyup')` (*It's not the native `keyup` event from the DOM.*)

Here, your `TextField` component never emit a `keyup` event, so your listener won't ever be triggered. Even if you have a component inside that triggers an event with the same name, this event isn't dispatch to the parents, only to its direct parent (i.e. the component using it).

What you have to do it emitting the event again while listening to it.

```html
<TextField label="Some Text" @keyup="updateLen" v-model="text"  />
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field @keyup="keyUp"></v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  keyUp(event) {
     this.content = this.content.replace(/([^a-z0-9-]+)/gi, '');
     this.$emit('input', this.content); // Updates `v-model`
     this.$emit('keyup', event); // Triggers your `@keyup` listener
  },
</script>
```

---

If your `TextField` component is only a wrapper to `v-text-field` and you expect it to have the exact same props / listeners, you can disable to auto inheritance of attributes and set it yourself.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   inheritAttrs: false, // The root element won't inherit all static attrs
}
</script>
```